# Positional Relationship in 4D

Tags: geometry

I don't know if the title is right... I'm not an English speaker...

Let's think about planes. In third dimension, only 3 kinds of positional relationship exists : parallel, share a straight line, exactly the same. However, in fourth some relationships can be added. For example, $xy$ plane and $zw$ plane share only one point $(0, 0, 0, 0)$. What are the other relationships in fourth dimension?

Comment: The possible relations are "parallel" (a.k.a. non-intersecting), "intersect in a point," "intersect in a line," and "the same." It's essentially a consequence of the Rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Each $2$-dimensional hyperplane in $4$D is determined as the set of solutions of two linear equations. The points in their intersection would be solutions of the system obtained by putting together all $4$ equations. The relative position in $2$ and $3$D is given according to the dimension of that intersection. A possible classification is simply extending that criterion. What are the possible dimensions that the intersection can have? $-1$ (for the empty case), $0,1,2$. There are more conditions that you might want to extend. For example, in $3$D two lines might have empty intersection ...

Comment: ... in two different ways: The lines could be contained in a plane, and parallel, or they are not contained in a plane. A similar thing can happen in $4$D. The $2$D planes could be non-intersecting while being contained in a $3$D hyperplane, or not.

Comment: It seems that rank-theorem is quite difficult for me to understand...  This is an another question in any way : 1. Can a straight line and a plane can be skewed(I'm not sure if this word choice is correct, sorry;;) in 4D? 2. In order for two planes to be skewed, 5D is needed?    As far as I think, both would be right..

Comment: Yes, it is what I said above. Two $2$D affine subspaces (ordinary planes) inside $4$-dimensional affine space can be non-intersecting in two ways: (1) being parallel, in which case they will be contained in a single $3$-dimensional affine subspace. (2) not contained in a $3$D affine subspace. Examples: The $2$-planes $\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4:\ x+y+z+t=1=y+z+t\}$ and $\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4:\ x+y+z+t=2, 1=y+z+t\}$ are non-intersecting and parallel. They are contained in the $3$D affine subspace $\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4:\ y+z+t=1\}$. ...

Comment: ... If you replace the second with $\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4:\ x+y+z+t=2, 1=\mathbf{2}y+z+t\}$. Then, they are also non-intersecting, but this time there is no $3$D affine subspace containing them both.

Comment: Interesting coincidence that this question was asked at almost exactly the same time as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878325).

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector subspaces of dimension $n_V$ and $n_W$ respectively in a $\mathbb{R}^n$ space. Using that $$dim(U \cap V)=dim(U)+dim(V)-dim(U+V)$$ we can conclude the that $$max\{dim(U)+dim(V)-n,0\} \le dim(U \cap V) \le min\{dim(U),dim(V)\}.$$

Hyperplanes can be seen as a point+a vector subspace. Let's consider that both planes cut the origin, then they can essentially be seen as two subspaces. In your case, $n_V=n_W=2$, since we have two planes; and n=4. Therefore, the dimension of the vector subspaces intersection is $0 \le dim(U \cap V) \le 2$. The planes can be the same plane, cut in a line, or cut in a single point. We must also consider the case where one of them does not cut the origin (we can always make a translation so that one of them cuts the origin). In this case, the planes can be parallel, cut in a line, cut in a point or cross in space without cutting. However, I don't see a straightforward way to prove it.

An intuitive way of "seeing" in 4D is using color as the fourth dimension. Imagine that the red color equals to w=1 and blue to w=2. Imagine a red z=0 plane, and a blue y=0 plane. Both planes cross without cutting, because they have different w (color).

Comment: For flats that don’t include the origin, you can use a standard model of the projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ as various equivalence classes of $\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$, which will let you apply the above theorems.